# How to do post and get with backbonejs to php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

How to do post and get with backbonejs to php?
below is my code, one is ajax way it work fine will post and grab output message. but I'm learning backbonejs now, is it correct use fetch() to get and save() to post? How to output same result like ajax way?
Thanks.

php

```
<div class="con">
<?php 
if($_POST){
    // print_r($_POST);
    print $_POST['name'];
}else{
    print 'error';
}
?>
</div>
```

ajax
js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inserts.php",
    data: { name: "tim"}
}).done(function( msg ) {
    var con = $(msg).filter('.con').html();
    console.log(con);
});
```

output => print $_POST['name'] =>tim

backbone
js

```
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true; 
Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // defaults: {
    // name: 'undefined',
    // age: 'undefined'
    // },
    urlRoot: "inserts.php",
});
person = new Person({name:"tim"});
person.save();
```

UPDATE

```
person.save({
    success: function(model,response, options){
        console.log('success'); => nothing output
        => and how to output 'tim' in console.log 
    },
    error: function(model, xhr, options){

    }
});
```

Comment: Save() does a POST if the model doesn't have an ID and a PUT when it does. Your code works fine. The PHP should return a 201/204 header on success or 40x on an error. The save() takes success and error callbacks as options to monitor the response.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Would you show me some code example how to monitor the response? just like print the result same ajax doing print tim .

Comment: I don't use PHP, but http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
person.save({
  success: function(model, response, options) {
  },
  error: function(model, xhr, options) {
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, please see my update I tried your code would you show me some code for example

Comment: I would expect the console.log to print something. Since it didn't, I would use the dev tools on a browser to debug what's going on.

1. Is it sending a request?
2. Is the request accurate?
3. Is the response accurate?
4. Are there any errors?